# Unable to upload picture onto my website using HTML

Tags: html, css, dropbox, imgur

I have been trying to add an image onto my website and tried using both imgur.com and dropbox.com. I used the  tag but it wont work and I have attached an image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5AEE.jpg

Comment: You should check that the service you're using to host your images allows you to display them directly on external sites. Most free image hosts don't allow this.

Answer (score 2):

I right clicked on the image and copied the image url address and used that url instead. Hope that fixes your problem.

New link:

```
https://uc69060076c57c1d4e10a3d6b967.previews.dropboxusercontent.com/p/thumb/ABh9znZ4buVIgJpCNaaA9R_Tld0W8TRb9DYLP-L1cCI0sRQHXYjqW4ROkYQP9OJcRmF1YSyM2rCGTZyotcoTVToa-GoO7EJG44HKotr2DuUNFn37FrXbG7zkN-ypKuDNZNl0ApjnBfA0d8fsOwZH-GdaVGHW59S7HPc-g8qma-yPaU6IwmUu2Ksw23fDmHm5LxZQbyPWkWqx_SRsHSD35zHHK7MD7yoayOLWF-RLhFMzyPPFyRW9zOW0HbjFZjIIcwY-hNcEUauqmwbuZuaUwgdQ1C8BcimaBUgH8VYFKJDy8acgKs8HUSsoKhX2P812ZyvwQiU9PSnbJa-ICQVoHqT6NSOcYr5FI6C6RFKwZ74SppkrkDkt6NtIXAgJhXbFSwKmiqyyuxbVbGQ7hMmNmnwDY0A3f-nByqHnU1kYAN1VnA/p.png
```

Also your open `background:`  could break your css so I removed that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Geetu Lalchandani</title>

<style>
    body {
        text-align: center;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    input {
        border: 0;
        padding: 12px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
        background: gray;
    }
   
</style>

</head>

<body>
<img alt="Profile Picture" src="https://uc69060076c57c1d4e10a3d6b967.previews.dropboxusercontent.com/p/thumb/ABh9znZ4buVIgJpCNaaA9R_Tld0W8TRb9DYLP-L1cCI0sRQHXYjqW4ROkYQP9OJcRmF1YSyM2rCGTZyotcoTVToa-GoO7EJG44HKotr2DuUNFn37FrXbG7zkN-ypKuDNZNl0ApjnBfA0d8fsOwZH-GdaVGHW59S7HPc-g8qma-yPaU6IwmUu2Ksw23fDmHm5LxZQbyPWkWqx_SRsHSD35zHHK7MD7yoayOLWF-RLhFMzyPPFyRW9zOW0HbjFZjIIcwY-hNcEUauqmwbuZuaUwgdQ1C8BcimaBUgH8VYFKJDy8acgKs8HUSsoKhX2P812ZyvwQiU9PSnbJa-ICQVoHqT6NSOcYr5FI6C6RFKwZ74SppkrkDkt6NtIXAgJhXbFSwKmiqyyuxbVbGQ7hMmNmnwDY0A3f-nByqHnU1kYAN1VnA/p.png">

    <p>Hey! I'm Geety</p>
    <p>I am a recent graduate from the University of Waterloo Biomedical Science Program and am excited to jump into th eworld of Software Engineering!</p>
    <p>If you are interested in connecting with me drop your email below: </p>

    <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email">
    <input type="submit">
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use, which I was able to get by doing an inspect element on the image in Imgur to get the actual image url

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP9Eo.png" />
```

[image]